# Shell: Printing "" in a file with echo

Tags: shell

I want to add the following line:

```
%optflags "-O2"
```

In a file a.txt using shell.
When I write:

```
{ echo "%optflags "-O2""
    } >> a.txt
```

It prints:

```
 %optflags -O2
```

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the double quotes:

```
echo "%optflags \"-O2\""
```

or

Use single quotes:

```
echo '%optflags "-O2"'
```

Note: you can partly see what was going on with your original code if you check it in `bash -x`:

```
$ echo "%optflags "-O2""
+ echo '%optflags -O2'
```

It passed a *single* argument to `echo`.. Why? Well, it concatenated `"%optflags "`, `-O2`, and `""` (the empty string) to a single argument.